# Pyinstaller build fails on windows because argparse (WARNING: stderr: SystemExit: 2)

Tags: python, windows, build, pyinstaller, argparse

I have this project  [qrTransfer](https://github.com/WesleyMPG/qrTransfer/) about sending files between PCs and mobile devices using a QrCode. I want to create a dev build for Windows with the current dev [code](https://github.com/WesleyMPG/qrTransfer/tree/c61c5bea4a46ddb5dadd857e82674c05fc698e29) but I get the error below running pyinstaller. However, on Linux I can build with no problem. Lastly, the last build for Windows was made about one year and a half ago and I forgot to add in the docs the Pyinstaller version used, but I'm pretty sure it was the latest at the time.

The error:

```
 usage: _child.py [-h] [-p path_list [path_list ...]] [-ptm] [-mtp] [--remote] [--debug]
 _child.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 732 824
67802 WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
 Traceback (most recent call last):
67802 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
   File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
67802 WARNING: stderr:   File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
   File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
67802 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
67802 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 205, in _console_script_run
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 205, in _console_script_run
67802 WARNING: stderr:     run()
     run()
67802 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 189, in run
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 189, in run
67802 WARNING: stderr:     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
67802 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
67802 WARNING: stderr:     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
67802 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1033, in main
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1033, in main
67802 WARNING: stderr:     build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
     build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 973, in build
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 973, in build
67818 WARNING: stderr:     exec(code, spec_namespace)
     exec(code, spec_namespace)
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\qrTransfer.exe.spec", line 4, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\qrTransfer.exe.spec", line 4, in <module>
67818 WARNING: stderr:     a = Analysis(
     a = Analysis(
67818 WARNING: stderr:         ^^^^^^^^^
         ^^^^^^^^^
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 466, in __init__
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 466, in __init__
67818 WARNING: stderr:     self.__postinit__()
     self.__postinit__()
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
67818 WARNING: stderr:     self.assemble()
     self.assemble()
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in assemble
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in assemble
67818 WARNING: stderr:     self.binaries.extend(find_binary_dependencies(self.binaries, collected_packages))
     self.binaries.extend(find_binary_dependencies(self.binaries, collected_packages))
67818 WARNING: stderr:                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 216, in find_binary_dependencies
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 216, in find_binary_dependencies
67818 WARNING: stderr:     child.call(import_library, package)
     child.call(import_library, package)
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 319, in call
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 319, in call
67818 WARNING: stderr:     raise RuntimeError(f"Child process call to {function.__name__}() failed with:\n" + output)
     raise RuntimeError(f"Child process call to {function.__name__}() failed with:\n" + output)
67818 WARNING: stderr: RuntimeError: Child process call to import_library() failed with:
 RuntimeError: Child process call to import_library() failed with:
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_child.py", line 63, in run_next_command
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_child.py", line 63, in run_next_command
67818 WARNING: stderr:     output = function(*args, **kwargs)
     output = function(*args, **kwargs)
67818 WARNING: stderr:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 194, in import_library
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Envs\qrt\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 194, in import_library
67818 WARNING: stderr:     __import__(package)
     __import__(package)
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\display\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\display\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
67818 WARNING: stderr:     from .qrWindow import qr_window
     from .qrWindow import qr_window
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\display\qrWindow.py", line 9, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\display\qrWindow.py", line 9, in <module>
67818 WARNING: stderr:     from utils import ROOT_DIR
     from utils import ROOT_DIR
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
67818 WARNING: stderr:     from .logger import logger
     from .logger import logger
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\logger.py", line 3, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\logger.py", line 3, in <module>
67818 WARNING: stderr:     from .cli import args
     from .cli import args
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\cli.py", line 79, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\cli.py", line 79, in <module>
67818 WARNING: stderr:     args = setup_arg_parser()
     args = setup_arg_parser()
67818 WARNING: stderr:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\cli.py", line 45, in setup_arg_parser
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\Documents\qrTransfer\src\utils\cli.py", line 45, in setup_arg_parser
67818 WARNING: stderr:     return parser.parse_args()
     return parser.parse_args()
67818 WARNING: stderr:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py", line 1872, in parse_args
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py", line 1872, in parse_args
67818 WARNING: stderr:     self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
     self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py", line 2630, in error
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py", line 2630, in error
67818 WARNING: stderr:     self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
     self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
67818 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\win-builder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py", line 2617, in exit
   File "C:\Users\win-builder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py", line 2617, in exit
67818 WARNING: stderr:     _sys.exit(status)
     _sys.exit(status)
67818 WARNING: stderr: SystemExit: 2
 SystemExit: 2
```

Usually I build with this [script](https://github.com/WesleyMPG/qrTransfer/blob/6f2b81bb30d4f1d439dd57fd938269bc5fba5e50/src/scripts/windows/build.bat) (I know there are regular '/'s in the last --add-data but fixing it changes nothing), but running Pyinstaller directly also gives the same error

```
@echo off

setlocal 
cd /d %~dp0

set root=..\..
set out=..\%root%\build

if not exist %out% (
    mkdir %out%
)

if exist %out%\dist (
    rmdir /Q /S %out%\dist
)


pyinstaller^
 --add-data "%root%\display\kvFiles;display\kvFiles"^
 --add-data "%root%\resources;resources"^
 --add-data "%root%/server/templates;server/templates"^
 --icon "%root%\resources\icon.ico"^
 --onefile --distpath "%out%\dist"^
 --workpath "%out%\build" -n qrTransfer.exe "%root%\main.py"
```

Here is where I setup the [argparse](https://github.com/WesleyMPG/qrTransfer/blob/c61c5bea4a46ddb5dadd857e82674c05fc698e29/src/utils/cli.py)

```
import argparse, sys
from pathlib import Path

__all__ = ['args']


def setup_arg_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Provides a QRcode to download or upload a file. \
        Commands described here take server\'s point of view. Have in \
        mind that '
    )

    parser.add_argument('-p',
                        metavar='path_list',
                        dest='path_list',
                        nargs='+',
                        help='- Paths to the files which download code \
                        will be generated. (Only -ptm mode)')

    parser.add_argument('-ptm',
                        '--pc-to-mobile',
                        action='store_false',
                        help='- [DEFAULT] Starts the program to upload \
                        a file to other device')

    parser.add_argument('-mtp',
                        '--mobile-to-pc',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='- Starts the program to download a file \
                        from another device'
    )

    parser.add_argument('--remote',
                        action='store_true',
                        dest='shall_remote_upload',
                        help='- Enables transfer through the remote \
                        service file.io'
    )

    parser.add_argument('--debug',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='- Enables debug mode.'
    )
    return parser.parse_args()


def validate_args(args):
    if  args.mobile_to_pc:
        args.pc_to_mobile = False
    else:
        validate_path_list(args)


def validate_path_list(args):
    if not args.path_list:
        print('Path (-p) not provided. Check help (-h) for more info.')
        sys.exit(1)

    paths = args.path_list
    for i, path_str in enumerate(paths):
        paths[i] = Path(path_str.strip()).absolute()
        validate_path(paths[i])


def validate_path(p : Path):
    if (p.is_file() or p.is_dir()): return True
    print(f'The path {p} does not exist.')
    sys.exit(1)


class MockArgs:
    mobile_to_pc = True
    pc_to_mobile = False
    debug = False


if not 'pytest' in sys.modules:
    args = setup_arg_parser() 
    validate_args(args)
else:
    args = MockArgs()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(args.path_list)
```

Worth mentioning that I tried auto-py-to-exe and the result was the same. Also,  I saw the answer for a problem involving Pyinstaller and argparse saying I should change `parser.parse_args()` to `parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])` but still the result is the same.

Comment: The `usage` line does match your `parser` setup, but the `sys.argv` that it gets, `'732 824'` is not what your parser expects.  I'd suggest printing `sys.argv` to see what the parser has to work with.  Are you calling this script with ''-p', '-ptm' etc commandline values?.  With `argparse` this script should be run from a shell, not some 'pyinstaller' environment or shell.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyinstaller, but I don't think it should be 'running' this script.  It may put it in some useful place, but shouldn't actually call it with 'commandline' strings,

Comment: @hpaulj this is the content of sys.argv ['C:\\Users\\win-builder\\Envs\\qrt\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\isolated\\_child.py', '808', '972']. I think what's happening is my argparse definitions are mixed up with pyinstaller agparse definitions

Answer (score 1):

I have found a [workaround](https://github.com/WesleyMPG/qrTransfer/commit/1db3ea22f02a77cf7808f7679d7717e10dd90734). What seems to be happening is my argparse definitions are getting mixed up with some argparse definitions from Pyinstaller. Then, I have added a check to make sure that the args will be parsed only if the executed script is called "main.py"

```
name_of_main_file = Path(__main__.__file__).name
if not 'pytest' in sys.modules and name_of_main_file == 'main.py':
    args = setup_arg_parser() 
    validate_args(args)
else:
    args = MockArgs()
```